# How to extend (System.Net.Http)HttpClient Http Verbs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

Is it possible to add a new arbitrary HTTP Verb to System.Net.Http HttpClient?

Case in question:

I developed a WebAPI for an MVC-based document managment system.

The API supports:
GET - fetch a document, POST - create a new document, PUT - update a document, DELETE - delete a document.

I also need to support: PRINT - print a document, EMAIL - email a document.

It is easy to add the VERBs on the MVC side. Add the [AcceptVerbs("PRINT")] decoration and you are done.

BUT I need to instruct the developers using my API how to access it. Since they are using HttpClient my problem is: How will these VERBs be consumed using the HttpClient?

Dror

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are not standard HTTP verbs. I would not recommend you using them. If you insist on using them you could use the `SendAsync` method which allows you to specify the HTTP verb you want to use:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PRINT"), "http://example.com");
    var result = client.SendAsync(request);
}
```